# Activity shown in custom cell view

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-cell

I have to create a screen displaying various activity in the user's account such as picture like, uploading images and videos. Just like this-

[image: 1st activity containing picture]
[image: 2nd activity containing liking]

I thought of using custom TableViewCell for which I need to make two different custom cells in a same table view. I had no problem while making a custom cell for the 2nd activity but am facing problem for the first activity as I have to add an UIImageView for the picture and video. The height of view is not increasing along with UIImage added. Can anyone tell me how can I make two different shapes of custom cells or should I use some other way to show the activities?

Comment: is autolayout enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate cell height for different cells. Here is how I do with this:

```
+(CGFloat)heightForBubbleWithObject:(MessageModel *)object
{
    CGSize retSize = object.size;
    if (retSize.width == 0 || retSize.height == 0) {
        retSize.width = MAX_SIZE;
        retSize.height = MAX_SIZE;
    }else if (retSize.width > retSize.height) {
        CGFloat height =  MAX_SIZE / retSize.width  *  retSize.height;
        retSize.height = height;
        retSize.width = MAX_SIZE;
    }else {
        CGFloat width = MAX_SIZE / retSize.height * retSize.width;
        retSize.width = width;
        retSize.height = MAX_SIZE;
    }
    return 2 * BUBBLE_VIEW_PADDING + retSize.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ios 8 and above put this magical lines and make sure the constraints are properly given

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

there is a wonderful answer about this please refer it for the details [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)